# Exception takes 4 minutes to be thrown

Tags: c#, exception

I have a weird issue : i have some code surrounded by try.. catch

In the catch segment i am taking a screenshot of what happened.

The problem is that the exception takes few minutes to be thrown after the error condition, and so i get a screenshot of something else entirely.

What can be causing an exception to take few minutes to be thrown ?

Thanks

Code Added:

The WaitAndActivateWindow calls AutoIT to give focus to the offending window (method that is called throughout the code and takes ~ 0.2 sec to load.

```
try
{
    // Load AutoIt defaults.
    LoadDefaults();

    // HandleInstallation();

    // Some more actions here
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    this.WaitAndActivateWindow();
    ScreenShotUtility.TakeScreenShot(@"UnhandledError");

    Log(e.ToString());

    throw;
}
```

Comment: What's throwing the exception? What type is the exception?

Comment: I sthe exception a StackOverflowException ?

Comment: Are you getting timeouts on TCP sockets?

Comment: No, i simply detect some error condition in code and throw an ApplicationException. This is caught by the "global" exception handler (the try .. catch that basically surrounds most of the application's code).

Comment: You may want to log the time at the start of the catch block.. and after the Wait call, just in case it's taking longer while an exception is underway...

Comment: Is it possible that resolving symbols may be the issue? this is being run on a lab machine, with no access to the internet... perhaps it's timing out trying to get symbols for the code?

Comment: @liortal: seems quite unlikely that it's timing out trying to get symbols for the code.  If that were the problem, it'd be the case for a lot more people than you.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, put the time in the exception (since you seem to own the code?) at the point it's thrown and check it against the time on the first line of the catch.  If there really is 4 minutes between them, start having a look a razlebe's suggestions about where some of the time might be going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely that the exception is taking 4 minutes to be thrown. It's more likely, in my view, that something else that's being released as the stack is unwinding before your exception is caught is causing the delay.

I'd suspect:

- Open connections to external systems (database, network, etc.)
- Anything that's releasing a collection of objects that are all being destroyed. Have those objects got complex IDisposable logic, for example?

Running the code with the debugger and using a few judiciously-placed breakpoints should quickly narrow down the issue. @forsvarir's suggestion regarding capturing timestamps as you throw and catch the exception would also give you a helping hand.

Answer (score 0):

The most common case for me when an exception takes a long time to be thrown is that the OS (in my case Mac OS X) is writing a core dump to the file (I have my Mac configured to do this). That's one place to look, but I'm sure there are many other possibilities. (More information in the question might be helpful.)

Comment: Are symbols involved in any process of the exception mechanism? (trying to d/l symbols for the stack trace or something?)

Comment: As the exception is being caught, it's extremely unlikely that the OS is writing a core file (or equivalent).